# Delete file using linux

Tags: linux, file, directory, delete-file

This code is that I want to give  two directory and this code will look if these two directory contains two files that contains the same information, and asks me which file I want to delete .

I have written this code but I don't know how to write the code that will delete the file , please help

```
#!bin/bash
echo "give the first directory"
read firstdir

echo "give the second directory"
read seconddir

for i in ` ls $firstdir`

do

echo $i

t= `md5sum $firstdir/$i`

s= `md5sum $seconddir/$i`

if [ "$t" ! = "$s" ]

then

echo " of which directory will be eliminated? $i"

read direct

( here I want the code to delete the directory ex : delete  direct/i )

fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo " of which directory will be eliminated? $i"

read direct

( here I want the code to delete the directory ex : delete  direct/i )
```

With:

```
echo "of which directory will be eliminated? $i:
1)$firstdir
2)$seconddir
"
read -p "(1/2)" direct
case $direct in
        1)
                rm -v $firstdir/$i
        ;;
        2)
                rm -v $seconddir/$i
        ;;
        *)
        echo "ERROR: bad value, 1 or 2 expected!" ; exit 1
esac
```

Comment: Welcome :) please vote up my solution and accept it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this. I just made my own solution based on your requirements. I hope you like it. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

# check for a valid first directory
while true
do
    echo "Please, enter the first directory"
    read FIRST_DIR

    if [ -d $FIRST_DIR ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Invalid directory"
    fi
done

# check for a valid second directory    
while true
do
    echo "Please, give the second directory"
    read SECOND_DIR

    if [ -d $SECOND_DIR ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Invalid directory"
    fi
done


for FILE in `ls $FIRST_DIR`
do
    # make sure that only files will be avaluated
    if [ -f $FILE ]; then

        echo $SECOND_DIR/$FILE

        # check if the file exist in the second directory
        if [ -f $SECOND_DIR/$FILE ]; then

            # compare the two files
            output=`diff -c $FIRST_DIR/$FILE $SECOND_DIR/$FILE`

            if [ ! $output ]; then
                echo "Which file do you want to delete?
                1)$FIRST_DIR/$FILE
                2)$SECOND_DIR/$FILE
                "

                # read a choice
                read -p "(1/2)" choice

                # delete the chosen file
                case $choice in
                    1)
                        rm -v $FIRST_DIR/$FILE
                        ;;
                    2)
                        rm -v $SECOND_DIR/$FILE
                        ;;
                    *)
                        echo "ERROR invalid choice!"
                esac      
            fi
        else
            echo "There are no equal files in the two directories."
            exit 1  
        fi
    else
        echo "There are no files to be evaluated."
    fi
done
```